# Resizing the length of an array produced by conditional multiplying two other two arrays

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Assume that i have 3 arrays of integer which are arr1, arr2 and prod. Where, Arr1 and Arr2  have the same lengths, while prod will be size depends. And I'm trying the following code

```
for (int i =0; i < arr1.lenght; i++)
{        
    if (arr1[i]> 0 && arr2[i]> 0)
        prod[i]= arr1[i]*arr2[i];
}
```

How could I re-size the array prod in advance ? Could any help please ? many thanks.

Comment: Surely `prod` will be the same length as `arr1` and `arr2`

Comment: Do you need array? How about a list?

Comment: @ L.B and lukas .. could i do it with using array using  Linq ??

Comment: @ hamlet... how to do what you mentioned please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use LINQ:

```
int[] prod = arr1
    .Zip(arr2, (i, j) => Tuple.Create(i, j))
    .Where(t => t.Item1 > 0 && t.Item2 > 0)
    .Select(t => t.Item1 * t.Item2)
    .ToArray();
```

this will only contain products where the corresponding elements in `arr1` and `arr2` are positive.

EDIT: A slightly better way would be:

```
int[] prod = Enumerable.Range(0, arr1.Length)
    .Where(i => arr1[i] > 0 && arr2[i] > 0)
    .Select(i => arr1[i] * arr2[i])
    .ToArray();
```

which avoids creating intermediate tuples.

Comment: @Qaesar - `i` and `j` are the names of the corresponding elements in `arr1` and `arr2`. Zip creates a sequence of tuples (arr[i], arr2[i]) for each index `i`.

Comment: I got it Lee. and sorry for deleting my comment. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

Use collections. For example [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

```
List<int> prod = new List<int>();
for (int i =0; i < arr1.lenght; i++)
{
   if (arr1[i]> 0 && arr2[i]> 0)
   prod.Add(arr1[i]*arr2[i]);
}
```

you can then create an array from List:

```
int[] prodArray = prod.ToArray();
```

if you want to maintain the connection between index in arr1 and index in multiplication result, you can use [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

```
Dictionary<int, int> prod = new Dictionary<int, int>();
for (int i =0; i < arr1.lenght; i++)
{
   if (arr1[i]> 0 && arr2[i]> 0)
   prod.Add(i, arr1[i]*arr2[i]);
}
```

Comment: @ Thorsten... what you means by "maintain the connection". I think using the both list and dictionary keep the same  index . Am I right ?

Comment: @Qaesar: It is Dmitry Dovgopoly's reply, but I think he means that if you want to know, which index in `arr1` and `arr2` produced the result (which you don't know when you just have a result array), you can use a dictionary. This would show you "the multiplication gave 3 results, and they were created by indices x, y and z".

Comment: e.g. arr1: {0,0,1} arr2{1,2,3}. then pordList will be {3}. And prodList[0] = 3; prodDict will be {(2,3)}. prodDict[0] - error. prodDict[2] = 3;

Comment: I got it .. Thank you a lot  Thorsten and Dmitry :)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a `List<int>`. This will dynamically resize based upon what is added. Performance of the insertion will be slower that with an `int[]` but depending on the size it may be marginal.

So you could do:

```
List<int> Prod = new List<int>();
for (int i =0; i < arr1.lenght; i++)
    if (arr1[i]> 0 && arr2[i]> 0)
        prod.Add(arr1[i]*arr2[i]);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> arr1 = new List<int>();
    List<int> arr2 = new List<int>();
    List<int> prod = new List<int>();

    arr1.AddRange(new int[] { 1, 0, 1 });
    arr2.AddRange(new int[] { 1, 1, 0 });

    prod = arr1.Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
        .Join(arr2.Select((item, index) => new { item, index }), i => i.index, i => i.index, (a, b) => a.item * b.item)
        //Where makes it variable
        .Where(i => i > 0)
        .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following LINQ:

```
int[] prod = (from x in Enumerable.Range(0, array1.Length).Select((z) => array1[z] * array2[z]) where x != 0 select x).ToArray();
```

This makes use of the fact that `0` can only be the result of multiplication if one of the factors was 0, too.

**EDIT**
I missed a bit in your question. You want to multiply entries where both factors are *positive*. In that case, you should go witht the LINQ code that @Lee gave.

**EDIT 2**
I just read your comment on an answer that suggested to use a dictionary so you can later see which index produced which result:

> what you means by "maintain the connection". I think using the both list 
>   and dictionary keep the same index . Am I right ?

All the solutions given here produce lists or arrays that have a less or equal number of elements than `arr1` and `arr2`. This means that in the worst case you don't know, which index produced the result of multiplication.

The code in your original answer ships around this: The `prod` array needs to have the same number of elements as `arr1` and `arr2`, as otherwise you'd get an exception.

In turn, elements that are `0` in the `prod` array can only be the result of one of `arr1` or `arr2` being `<= 0` at this index. This is information you lose when creating a list - thus the suggestion of using a dictionary, which maps the index to the result, but still contains less elements.